# Is it appropriate to use extension methods to map one class to another

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Just getting my feet wet with extension methods and am currently developing some mapping logic to convert an application Invoice to a Quickbooks Invoice. Thought it might be a good idea to have .Convert() extension method.

```
public static QBInvoice Convert(this InvoiceHeader importedInvoice)
```

The conversion is just field mapping of one class to another. But then I read somewhere that an extension method is to extend the original class, not convert it to another. Hence why I am asking. I know technically I can do it, but is it best practice compliant or taboo?

Comment: If `InvoiceHeader` is defined in your code, there's no need to write an extension method. Just put the method in the class. Having said that, there's nothing wrong with writing an extension method that converts something.

Comment: @Blorgbeard it is, but our app integrates with multiple financials applications: Quickbooks, Sage, etc. So we didn't want to clutter up our original InvoiceHeader class with conversion methods as all conversion logic will be in each of their respective Financials adapter project.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I like to use explicit casts so:

```
public class InvoiceHeader
{
   public static explicit operator QBInvoice(InvoiceHeader invoice)
   {
      return new QBInvoice {}; // do your mapping
   }
}
```

Then you can just cast it:

```
var qbInvoice = (QBInvoice) invoiceHeader;
```

Comment: that is a new concept for me, explicit casting. I didn't know you could do that. Thanks. I can see that as an alternative as well.

Comment: Here is some reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx and msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

Answer (score 2):

we use it to map classes all the time... probably not the best solution but at least you hide boring unnecessary code somewhere far away and make the code that matters (your business logic) nice and readable.

I must strongly disagree with Blogbeard's comment above: mapping between classes has nothing to do with the class itself (SRP) so putting that code outside either of the two classes is way cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks @Zdrakvo. Why would it not be the best solution?

Comment: my favorite way to map between objects is using some sort of mapper that would do that automatically. there are several popular ones, none is perfect. but they all as a bare minimum would map properties with same names plus allow some form of configuration or convention how to map the rest... I do not suggest reinventing the wheel but evaluate you own situation and write your own get an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

A great well-accepted conversion method for classes, defined as an extension method is [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx). `AsEnumerable`, `ToList`, and `ToDictionary` are other well-accepted "conversion" extension methods.

"To" or "As" seem to be acceptable naming conventions for extension methods which convert to another type, just as "On" is part of a standard naming convention for events.

Comment: @Chad `Convert` could be improved on by following this convention. That way if you need a convert with a different return type, you won't end up with mixed conventions or the lack of one.